# How to determine maxResolution and numZoomLevels in dynamic environment?

Tags: openlayers-2, latitude-longitude, resolution

I want to determine resolution and number of zoom level dynamically instead of inputting the values in openlayers client. When the user move the position on map by dragging or panning control, I can track the updated Lat-lon and get the min and max lat-lon. Now, I would like to calculate the resolution and maxzoomLevel for newly calculated latlon position when each time user changes the map position.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didnt understand your question very well but you can do sth when your zoomend end:

// zoom end or move end(change zoomend)

```
  map.events.register('zoomend', this, function (event) {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();       
    if( currentZoom  > 5)
    {
        // do something;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aragon.I used the concept like you mentioned above and passed the zoom level value by POST.Now.I can get the zoom level dynamically now based on parent map.
Thanks

Comment: Currently, I am dynamically passing the resolution value based on zoom level, by which I can restrict the minzoom level. But,I am facing the issue of "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/149189.png"" while trying to get the base layer.And I have blank base layer. And also I noticed, i am in zoom level lets say 16, but OSM is trying to get the tiles for zoom level 0, as you can see above the error message.
Do any body have any idea regarding this issue?
Thanks